# Android edittext soft keyboard disappear when click outside edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have edittext when I want to use clipboard or click outside edittext soft keyboard is disappear. How I can fix it any idea

Answer (score 0):

If you return true from your overrided method onEditorAction, system does not going to handle the action again. So, In this case you should return true to not hide keyboard when action is EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE.

Here use this code:

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
          if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

          }
          return true;
      }
 });
```